# How to remove all tags from Liquid template?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, liquid

I have this [Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) template:

```
Hello, {% foo %} world!
```

I would like to remove the `foo` tag from here and all other tags too, to obtain a clean document, without any `Liquid` markup:

```
Hello, world!
```

Is it possible to do this by using existing `Liquid` tools?

Answer (score 0):

Using the lexer from [Python Liquid](https://github.com/jg-rp/liquid), you can grab tokens that are literal template text, then join the token values back together. This removes output expressions (`{{ ... }}`) as well as tags.

```py
from liquid.lex import get_lexer
from liquid.token import TOKEN_LITERAL

tokenize = get_lexer()
template = "Hello, {% foo %} world!"
tokens = tokenize(template)  # an iterator
template_text = "".join(t.value for t in tokens if t.type == TOKEN_LITERAL)

print(template_text) # Hello,  world!
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of Python Liquid.